# cv2.CascadeClassifier resizing image before prediction fails

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, python

I have a code that takes a video file and uses cv2.CascadeClassifier to draw a rectangle over the face. However, the initial video has frames sized 720*1280*3. So I want to resize them before predicting.

```
from skimage.transform import rescale
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('/Users/user/Desktop/300wv/001/vid.avi')
desired_squared_shape = 128

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # resize whilst manintaing scale start 
    y, x, _ = frame.shape
    val = max(x, y)
    scaling_fac = desired_squared_shape / val

    image_rescaled = rescale(frame, scaling_fac, anti_aliasing=False, multichannel=True)

    y1, x1, _ = image_rescaled.shape

    width_pad = int((desired_squared_shape - y1) / 2)  # for both sides
    height_pad = int((desired_squared_shape - x1) / 2)

    image_rescaled = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image_rescaled,
                                    width_pad,
                                    (desired_squared_shape - y1) - width_pad,
                                    height_pad,
                                    (desired_squared_shape - x1) - height_pad, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)


    image_rescaled = image_rescaled.astype(np.uint8)

    # resize whilst maintaining scale end

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_rescaled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', image_rescaled)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I comment out the section 'resize whilst maintaining scale' start to end and use frame to create gray it works but it won't work with resized image

Comment: Where is the `rescale` function defined?

Comment: from skimage.transform import rescale